# Python test discovery with doctests, coverage and parallelism

Tags: python, unit-testing, discovery, python-coverage

... and a pony! No, seriously. I am looking for a way to organize tests that "just works". Most things do work, but not all pieces fit together. So here is what I want:

- Having tests automatically discovered. This includes doctests. Note that the sum of doctests must not appear as a single test. (i.e. not what py.test --doctest-modules does)
- Being able to run tests in parallel. (Something like py.test -n from xdist)
- Generating a coverage report.
- Make `python setup.py test` just work.

My current approach involves a `tests` directory and the [load_tests protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol). All files contained are named like `test_*.py`. This makes `python -m unittest discover` just work, if I create a file `test_doctests.py` with the following content.

```
import doctest
import mymodule1, mymodule2
def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(mymodule1))
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(mymodule2))
    return tests
```

This approach also has the upside that one can use setuptools and supply `setup(test_suite="unittest2.collector")`.

However this approach has a few problems.

- coverage.py expects to run a script. So I cannot use unittest2 discovery here.
- py.test does not run load_tests functions, so it does not find the doctests and the `--doctest-modules` option is crap.
- nosetests runs the `load_tests` functions, but does not supply any parameters. This appears totally broken on the side of nose.

How can I make things work better than this or fix some of the issues above?

Comment: Nice. Your question was just the answer I was looking for. :-) Regarding coverage.py: Using `coverage -m unittest2 discover` should work (at least it does for `unittest` in Py2.7).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but the problem still persists for some of us!  I was just working through it and found a solution similar to kaapstorm's, but with much nicer output.  I use `py.test` to run it, but I think it should be compatible across test runners:

```
import doctest
from mypackage import mymodule

def test_doctest():
    results = doctest.testmod(mymodule)
    if results.failed:
        raise Exception(results)
```

What I end up with in a failure case is the printed stdout output that you would get from running doctest manually, with an additional exception that looks like this:

```
Exception: TestResults(failed=1, attempted=21)
```

As kaapstrom mentioned, it doesn't count tests properly (unless there are failures) but I find that isn't worth a whole lot provided the coverage numbers come back high :)

Answer (score 1):

I use nose, and found your question when I experienced the same problem.

What I've ended up going with is not pretty, but it does run the tests.

```
import doctest
import mymodule1, mymodule2

def test_mymodule1():
    assert doctest.testmod(mymodule1, raise_on_error=True)

def test_mymodule2():
    assert doctest.testmod(mymodule2, raise_on_error=True)
```

Unfortunately it runs all the doctests in a module as a single test. But if things go wrong, at least I know where to start looking. A failure results in a DocTestFailure, with a useful message:

```
DocTestFailure: <DocTest mymodule1.myfunc from /path/to/mymodule1.py:63 (4 examples)>
```

Comment: While it works with nose, the failure messages are total crap now. Imo, this is just beyond useful. I'd consider this solution inferior to the presented alternative.