# How can I integrate doctests with unittest's test discovery?

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, doctest

I wrote a python script to do all my tests automatically for me, and generate a HTML report. I discovered `discover` for unittests the other day which lets me run all the unittests in a given directory without explicitly naming them, and I'd really like to be able to do my doctests the same way, rather than having to import each module explicitly.

I found some info on how to do this at https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html but didn't really get it. Could you please help me with using `discover` with my doctests?

[Python test discovery with doctests, coverage and parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982514/python-test-discovery-with-doctests-coverage-and-parallelism) is related, but still doesn't answer my question.

**coverage_module**

```
import coverage
import doctest
import unittest
import os

# import test_module 
import my_module

cov = coverage.Coverage()
cov.start()

# running doctest by explicity naming the module
doctest.testmod(my_module)

# running unittests by just specifying the folder to look into
testLoad = unittest.TestLoader()
testSuite = testLoad.discover(start_dir=os.getcwd())
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(testSuite)

cov.stop()
cov.save()
cov.html_report()
print "tests completed"
```

**test_module**

```
import unittest
import doctest

from my_module import My_Class


class My_Class_Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # setup variables

    def test_1(self):
        # test code

# The bit that should load up the doctests? What's loader, tests, and ignore though? 
# Is this in the right place?
def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(module_with_doctests))
    return tests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: `pytest` is considered etalon for tests in Python nowadays, so I'd recommend checking it out. Looks like it has a nice support for doctests too: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/doctest.html

Comment: Here's how I have done it in pytest. See this:
https://medium.com/@vladyslav.krylasov/discover-unit-tests-and-doctests-in-one-run-c5504aea86bd

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets figure out what's happening there

1) **unittest.discovery**

It has no clue of doctests as doctests is a different framework. 
So `unittest` isn't supposed to discover doctests out of the box.
That means you'll need to glue them together by hand

2) **doctest**

It's essentially a separate framework although it has some glueing classes to convert doctests into unittest-like TestCases. 
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/doctest.html#doctest.DocTestSuite

3) **discover**

Didn't get what `discover` you mean, I suppose it's

```
python -m unittest discover
```

If not and you're talking about https://pypi.python.org/pypi/discover then just forget about it - it's a backport for earlier versions of python

4) **what to do**

either scatter a lot of `load_tests` hooks across your code as described here https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/doctest.html#unittest-api or code a method to collect all the modules your have in one place and convert them into a DocTestSuite[s] https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/doctest.html#doctest.DocTestSuite

But honestly neither approach makes any sense nowadays as it boils down to:

```
$ py.test --doctest-modules
```

or

```
$ nosetests --with-doctest
```

Of course `coverage` and lots of bells & whistles are also supplied by these frameworks and you may keep sticking to unittest.TestCase, and you won't even need to create a *coverage_module* so I would dig into one of them rather then trying to come up with your own solution

Comment: I'm so sad no solution is proposed using standard library, first by principle, but most practically because I'm working in a normative constrained environment where, good or ill, I'm not allowed to installed third-party libraries (even pytest!).